# mysql - recursive query for similar records

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have two tables with below constructions:

```
create table article (
id    int         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
text  text,
date  timestamp   NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

create table article_relate (
article_id_1  int NOT NULL,
article_id_2  int NOT NULL
);
```

Example records in table "article"

```
id            title
--------------------------------------
1             About Ferrari
2             About Lamborghini
3             About my friends
4             About my kitchen
```

In the second table - "article_relates", I described the relations of similar themed records from the first table.

```
article_id_1       article_id_2
-----------------------------------
    1                  2
    2                  1
```

when I add the next article, I will link it to the first article I know about identical subject matter.

`Insert into article (id, title) values (5, 'About Maserati');`
and a link to a similar article with id = 2
`Insert into article_relate (article_id_1, article_id_2) values (5, 2);`
`Insert into article_relate (article_id_1, article_id_2) values (2, 5);`

Now I want to send a query to the database to get all entries related to the article about id = 5. Also, those entries with which the article about id = 2 is associated. The result for this query should be records with id = 5, 2 and 1

What query should be built to get this effect?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a JOIN clause:

```
SELECT article.id,
       article.name,
       article_relate.id AS article_relate_id
FROM article
LEFT JOIN article_relates ON article.id = article_relate.article_id_1
OR article.id = article_related
WHERE article.id = 5
```

will list all related articles for article id 5. does this help you?

about join in mysql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Would bind_param be needed for this? To close off the where claus. I actually don’t know but both answers did not mention it so assuming not.

Comment: @JeffBezos bind_param is used for adding parameters safely to queries. you should use it when you use user input as values in queries. not related to the question

Comment: Isn’t he inserting within his code? Insert into article.....Values (2 , 5)

Comment: I modified the query a bit to explain where the problem is. Unfortunately, it still has no intended effect. Thank you for your willingness to help. I appreciate @JeffBezos @ BenYitzhaki

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a select with an inner select query.

```
SELECT article.id,article.name FROM article WHERE article.id IN (SELECT article_id_2 from article_relate where article_id_1 = 5);
```